# Filter TreeViewer - Common Navigator Framework

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, filtering, package-explorer

I have a problem when trying to define a filter for folders or any other element within a project tree. My problem is that i want to show some sub-folders or sub-elements contained in one parent folder that i may want to hide/filter. If i filter the parent folder, then children folders or elements contained are filtered by default, and I am not able to show them in my tree view.

Initially i was using `PackageExplorerPart`, and now I'm getting into Common Navigator Framework. I would need to know if this filter behaviour is possible, using `PackageExplorerPart` or this `CommonNavigatorFramework`. Any aproach or documentation to start solving this problem would be very appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you filter the parent, the children are filtered by default. If you want only few of the children to be filtered, then you should set the filter on that pattern only - not on the parent

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer Prakash. What i actually need is to filter the parent folder. I mean, i need to set a view where only some user oriented information is shown, and i want to hide some "technical" folders. That is, i want to show children elements contained in this folder. This would imply this children elements to be shown at the parent folder level in the tree view hierarchy.

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Package Explorer. However, you are free to do this in the CNF framework. With CNF, you decide on what to show as the children of a node. You can even override the standard ones (like the hierarchy given by the folders and files) and give your own hierarchy.

Comment: For anyone interested in this issue, the solution was to rewrite the contentProvider class (extending ResourceExtensionContentProvider) method addChildren, and add to the returned Object array every element in the model tree except these folders we want to filter. So, children of those filtered folders will remain in the tree view, same level of their parent folders. Please feel free to suggest a better solution, if known!